# How do I add a variable as a default in a UserForm text box?

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, default, userform

In word vba, I have developed a UserForm with two text boxes.  For one of the text boxes I would like to add, as a default, a string variable that has already been defined and is calculated just before the form is displayed.  If textbox is "TextBox1" and the default string is "NewWord", how can I code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the value in the `Initialize` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.TextBox1.Text = "Default text to be displayed when the form is loaded."
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not familiar with the command "Me" can you please tell me what that is?

Comment: @LewisEigen: `Me` is the user form on which a control is placed. So the above means TextBox1 on the UserForm which contains this code. And if you type `Me.` you should get IntelliSense with a list of valid properties, including the control names.

Comment: Thanks, that hel[s a lot.